# Issues with deploying custom .msp file for Office 2010 via MDT 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, mdt-2010

Currently I have a working MDT 2010 server that has been humming along for awhile with no issues.  We've decided to upgrade to Office 2010 and I was trying to layer it into MDT as well.

It seems for some reason that it's not using the .msp file saved in the Updates folder during installation.  I've found several articles online to verify that I set it up the proper way (or so I think), yet something is still not working.

We used to do a full layered approach with MDT.  We would install the base OS and then install applications as needed.  But, we pretty much have the same programs on every computer so I sysprep and captured a machine when it was up to date.  Now with this Office install, I was just wanting to install it via a task sequence like we did on our previous solution (I still have it for reference even and it all appears to be setup the same).

I have added the application into the MDT workbench.  Created an entry in the task sequence telling it to run the program.  I have created a custom .msp file that tells it the key and a few other changes.  The .msp file is saved into the updates folder and all appears fine.

When I attempt to build a machine, it still prompts me for which version of Office I want instead of picking the ProPlus selection I've specified in the customization file.  I can't for the life of me figure out what is stopping it from reading that file.  I have tried modifying the .xml file even but it never saves the settings, I'm guessing maybe it doesn't want those settings used if it sees an .msp file in the folder(?).

I know this Office and .msp install work as I've manually installed it and had it auto-install via startup script on a dozen end-users, but when using it in MDT it seems to ignore the .msp file.  I've also tried to delete and recreate the .msp file in case of corruption.  All articles I find online look similar to what I've tried, which is pretty straightforward.

Thoughts?  Thanks!